# Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption

Tags: shiro

I want to use Apache Shiro with JSF. I made this configuration:

***Shiro.ini***

```
[main]
shiro.loginUrl = /platform/login.xhtml
dataSource = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
dataSource.requiredType = javax.sql.DataSource
dataSource.resourceName = global/alltech
dataSource.resourceRef = true
jdbcRealm = com.web.office.authentication.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 5000
multipleroles = com.web.office.authentication.MultipleRolesAuthorizationFilter

cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

[urls]
/platform/login.xhtml = authc
/authentication/passwordreset.xhtml = anon
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/** = authc
```

Login controller:

```
public void userAuthanticate() throws IOException, SQLException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {       
            Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, new Sha256Hash(password).toHex(), remember);
            token.setRememberMe(true);
            currentUser.login(token);

            if (currentUser.isAuthenticated())
            {
                FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
                NavigationHandler nh = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
                nh.handleNavigation(fc, null, "/platform/dashboard.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");
            }
        }
}
```

I use this code to create a password for user:

```
String encryptedpasswd = new Sha256Hash(selectedSystemUser.getPassword()).toHex();
```

Full Error:

```
2019-12-26 13:27:24,421 INFO  [org.apache.shiro.web.env.EnvironmentLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1069) Shiro environment initialized in 92 ms.
2019-12-26 13:27:24,423 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1069) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.9.SP01 for context '/Trading_platform'
2019-12-26 13:27:25,157 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1069) Running on PrimeFaces 7.0
2019-12-26 13:27:25,164 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 1069) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/Trading_platform' for server 'default-server'
2019-12-26 13:27:25,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "Trading_platform.war" (runtime-name : "Trading_platform.war")
2019-12-26 13:27:31,855 WARN  [org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager] (default task-2) There was a failure while trying to retrieve remembered principals.  This could be due to a configuration problem or corrupted principals.  This could also be due to a recently changed encryption key, if you are using a shiro.ini file, this property would be 'securityManager.rememberMeManager.cipherKey' see: http://shiro.apache.org/web.html#Web-RememberMeServices. The remembered identity will be forgotten and not used for this request.
2019-12-26 13:27:31,856 WARN  [org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager] (default task-2) Delegate RememberMeManager instance of type [org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.CookieRememberMeManager] threw an exception during getRememberedPrincipals().: org.apache.shiro.crypto.CryptoException: Unable to execute 'doFinal' with cipher instance [Cipher.AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, mode: decryption, algorithm from: SunJCE].
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:462)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:445)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.decrypt(JcaCipherService.java:390)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.decrypt(JcaCipherService.java:382)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager.decrypt(AbstractRememberMeManager.java:482)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager.convertBytesToPrincipals(AbstractRememberMeManager.java:419)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.mgt.AbstractRememberMeManager.getRememberedPrincipals(AbstractRememberMeManager.java:386)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.getRememberedIdentity(DefaultSecurityManager.java:612)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.resolvePrincipals(DefaultSecurityManager.java:500)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.createSubject(DefaultSecurityManager.java:346)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.Subject$Builder.buildSubject(Subject.java:845)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.web.subject.WebSubject$Builder.buildWebSubject(WebSubject.java:148)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.createSubject(AbstractShiroFilter.java:292)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:55)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
        at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:975)
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:1056)
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:853)
        at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:446)
        at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2208)
        at deployment.Trading_platform.war//org.apache.shiro.crypto.JcaCipherService.crypt(JcaCipherService.java:459)
        ... 60 more
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Are you just looking to hide the exception in the log? Or are you asking how to fix the "bad key" issue? https://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#byte-array-values

Comment: I'm asking how to fix the "bad key" issue.

Comment: Do you have a remember me key set?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it. using `UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, new Sha256Hash(password).toHex(), remember);
            token.setRememberMe(true);`

Comment: Take a look a the link above, that should be what you are looking for